# perl $csv->string() after calling $csv->combine( ) does not print expected data

Tags: perl, csv

Why is it when I call $csv->combine( ) and then $csv->string() that it does not return a string, but instead prints this: `Text::CSV=HASH(0x297f4a8)->string()`

Here's my sample code:

```
$csv->combine( [$request_cmd, $time_secs.".".$time_microsecs, $$, "-", "-"]);
print "string is $csv->string()\n";
```

and here is what is prints:

```
string is Text::CSV=HASH(0x297f4a8)->string()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not interpolating into the string because it's a method call.  Try:

```
print "string is ", $csv->string(), "\n";
```